# Delete table rows if table data does not contain a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a question regarding removing table rows within a table. I got the following HTML:

```
<table>
      <tr>
          <td class="html5badge"><a href="">autofocus</a></td>
          <td>autofocus</td>
          <td>Specifies that the drop-down list should automatically get focus when the page loads</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><a href="">disabled</a></td>
          <td>disabled</td>
          <td>Specifies that a drop-down list should be disabled</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="html5badge"><a href="">test</a></td>
          <td>autofocus</td>
          <td>Specifies that the drop-down list should automatically get focus when the page loads</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

I need a mechanism that looks whether the first `<td>` does not contain the `html5badge` class and delete the parent: `<tr>`.

To do this I created the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".onlyhtml5").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var classname = $('table tr td').not('.html5badge'); 
        console.log(classname)
        for (i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) { 
                $(classname[i].parentNode).remove();    
        }                
    });
});
```

This works but it does not exactly what I want. As you can see in my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yefuty9s/) it will delete all the table rows. But what I want is the following desired output:

```
<table>
      <tr>
          <td class="html5badge"><a href="">autofocus</a></td>
          <td>autofocus</td>
          <td>Specifies that the drop-down list should automatically get focus when the page loads</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="html5badge"><a href="">test</a></td>
          <td>autofocus</td>
          <td>Specifies that the drop-down list should automatically get focus when the page loads</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

The desired output is that the `<tr>` that contained the text: disabled is been removed! Based on the fact that the `<td>` within this `<tr>` does not contained the class: `html5badge`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `$('tr:not(:has(.html5badge))').remove();` - https://jsfiddle.net/fe9o3wf0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to retrieve the `tr` elements which do not contain `td.html5badge` and remove them:

```
$(".onlyhtml5").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('tr').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('td.html5badge').length == 0;
    }).remove();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yefuty9s/1/)

Comment: Awesome! Never used the filter function. Seems exactly what I want!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. The filter function is a great tool to use and very powerful: http://api.jquery.com/filter

Answer (score 1):

simply make it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".onlyhtml5").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('table tr td').not('.html5badge').each( funtion(){
           $( this ).parent().remove();
        } ); 
    });
});
```